# Button Click in C# using MVVM

Tags: c#, user-interface, plc

Hi guys i need help for making a code in C# for my UI. I am building some kind of a UI for controlling a FANUC industrial Robot and I have managed do do everything except to make logic for one command. So I need to make logic when some button for example JogA1 MINUS button is pressed UI needs to send TRUE value to PLC, when i release it it needs to send FALSE value to plc, also I am using MVVM pattern in C#.

**Here is my ViewModel:**

```
public ICommand MinusA1Command { get; private set; } 

public MainWindowViewModel()
{        
    MinusA1Command = new RelayCommand(async () => { await MinusA1(); });
}
```

**Here is the Model:**

```
public async Task  MinusA1()
{
      await Task.Run(() =>
      {
          var writeBuffer = new Byte[1];
          int writeResult = _client.DBWrite(5, 0, writeBuffer.Length, writeBuffer);

          S7.SetBitAt(ref writeBuffer, 0, 0, true);
      });
}
```

**Here is my View:**

```
<Button x:Name="Button1MINUS" Content="MINUS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="544,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156"  Command="{Binding MinusA1Command, Mode=OneWay}"  />
```

Comment: Use the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events: `<Button MouseDown="SomeCommand" ... />`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would bind the button `IsPressed` to a `bool` in the `ViewModel`

```
<Button IsPressed="{Binding MinusA1}" />
```

and in your `ViewModel`

```
private bool _minusA1;
public bool MinusA1 { 
    get { return _minusA1; } 
    set 
    { 
        _minusA1 = value;
        if(_minusA1) 
        {
            // IsPressed = true logic
        }
        else
        {
            // Not IsPressed = true logic
        }
    }
}
```